# Запуск video при попадании в зону видимости

Tags: javascript

Возможно ли сделать запуск видео при попадании в область видимости?
Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

```
<video src="spas_com2.mp4" controls="controls" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" height="auto" width="auto" style="max-width: 50%;padding-top: 20px;" class="spas_com2"></video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример как это можно реализовать. Как только `scrollTop` будет равен или больше верхней позиции элемента видео, то включится воспроизведение. Не все браузеры разрешают автовоспроизведение видео без атрибута `muted`.

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container");
const video = document.getElementById("video")
const videoRect = video.getBoundingClientRect();

container.addEventListener("scroll", (event) => {
  if (container.scrollTop >= videoRect.top) {
    video.play();
  };
});
```

```css
#container {
  overflow-y:scroll;
  height: 300px;
}
#video {
  margin: 600px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <video id="video" width="400" height="300" muted>
            <source src="https://joy1.videvo.net/videvo_files/video/free/2014-12/large_watermarked/Raindrops_Videvo_preview.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе добрый человек!